# Consistant Way to Catch C++ Library Crashes

Tags: c++, exception, memory, crash, atexit

I've looked around at different sites, and cannot find any answer to this question, other than ones that don't seem that they would work. As the title says, I am trying to find a way to catch if the library I am working on crashes. I have a Root class that holds instances of the many manager-style classes that I have in my library, and it releases the instances in it's destructor. Naturally, the managers are responsible for quite a bit of data, so if they are not properly disposed of there is a chance for a rather unacceptable, even dangerous level of memory leaks.

I am aware that, when a program crashes, that the OS will deallocate the stack space for the program, but that does not include calling the destructors of the allocated objects. It also does not include deleting any of the heap allocated during the execution, which is how I am dealing with a good deal of the memory in my library, which goes back to problem of widespread memory leaks.

A good deal of the answers I am coming across on other sites are just saying to register a function with `atexit()`, but that function does not work if the application crashes. And, as stated above, since crashes do not call destructors, there is no way to make a global singleton that closes everything when it is destroyed, which was my initial idea of how to deal with this. My other idea was to just hope that the end user of the library will take the proper precautions to avoid crashes (through widespread use of exception throwing), but I feel that goes against the idea of a well-coded library, and frankly I think it's asking a bit much of the end user to deal with that.

So I guess my TL;DR question is this: Is there a way, either through a standard C++ function, or through some sort of manager class, to catch when a library crashes and deal with it appropriately?

EDIT: Also, I would really prefer a cross platform way to deal with this. My code base heavily uses features of C++11, so I've programatically limited the useable compilers to the latest versions of GCC and Clang.

Not only that, but I also have a couple of classes, like a Logger, that will close their stream to the filesystem and print out a couple of messages about the exit status. I also have a memory tracker that reports any possible memory leaks to a file, but only in it's destructor.

Comment: On which operating system? With which compiler and compilation flags? if on Linux, on which distribution? Some Linux distributions have debugging variants of their system libraries.

Comment: "It also does not include deleting any of the heap allocated during the execution"  Generally it does.

Comment: The best way to handle crashes in your code is to **fix the bug that's causing them.**   Anything else is just a hack.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I kind of meant for it to be cross platform when I asked for a standard C++ function, but that was an assumption on my part, sorry. I updated the question.

Comment: @JohnDibling, of course, my eventual goal is to remove all the bugs, but that doesn't happen overnight :D. But I am also talking about instances where the end-user may not have caught an exception that I throw in my library.

Comment: @sm81095: Don't throw exceptions from a library.  Sounds like you are trying too hard to be *clever*, when what you should be focused on is being *robust*.

Comment: When a program crashes, all of its memory is automatically reclaimed by the OS.  It can't leak.  The same goes for any other resources used by your program.

Comment: Also @JohnDibling, I thought the whole point of memory leaks was when a program exits without deallocating the memory allocated with `new`.

Comment: @sm81095:  A memory leak occurs when you allocate memory and don't deallocate it.  That doesn't mean the OS won't clean it up when the program exits.

Comment: If there is a bug in your code that is causing these crashes, your first priority should be fixing that bug.  You should not even be thinking of writing yet more code to wallpaper over the bug.

Comment: @JohnDibling, I will look around for the platform specific memory deallocation processes. Other than that though, I updated my question to include a couple of other reasons I need to catch crashes. Also, while I appreciate your attempts and getting me to code better, I would appreciate an educated answer to my original question, be it a simple yes or no.

Comment: @sm81095:  You are asking us to show you the best way to write bad code.  Others might help you do that, but I'm going to stubbornly continue to try to teach you to write correct code in the first place.

Comment: @JohnDibling, I came here for an answer, not sass. There is not much point for you to be here on this question then. I'm sorry for getting frustrated but I want an answer to the question presented, not someone telling me the question I should have asked.

Comment: @sm81095:  I am also sorry that you're not willing to accept advice from people who see a bigger picture.  Best of luck then.  I was writing a detailed answer, but since you're not interested I'll just delete it.

Comment: @JohnDibling, I will gladly accept any answer that actually answers my actual question, but I don't want an answer that tells me I am asking the wrong question and then gives me something I don't need.

Comment: @JohnDibling Though having tools to ***find*** such bugs in big code bases and log some panic failure message or similar, fairly makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  Actually, I would think not, in general.  Having such tools as *part of* that big codeset can obfuscate dumps and make diagnosis just that much more difficult.  A global catch-all for example will catch an exception about to propogate out of `main` and let you do some logging before the system dies, but the callstack in the resulting dump file will be of no help in determining the actual cause of the crash.

Comment: That's not to say that using a catch-all is not a possible solution to finding these bugs; just that letting the system die immediatly is often a *better* solution.

Comment: @JohnDibling Sometimes, even having the information that the _system died immeadetly_ and unexpectedly at a particular point of time, and how often this occurred (for an automatically restarted system), could be very useful information for diagnosis of the fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Is there a way, either through a standard C++ function, or through some sort of manager class, to catch when a library crashes and deal with it appropriately?"*

The most concise answer for your question I can imagine is:

> Stick with the classes and categories of the [**C++ Standard Error handling**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error).

---

As you are asking for `atexit()`, the behaviour is well defined in the [standard reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) as well.

**Note** there are further handler mechanisms like the [`std::terminate_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler), that allow you to handle some exceptional abort situations, in a portable and standard compliant way.

Last but not least it might be necessary to install certain (OS specific) [signal handlers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal), to catch up errors like a so called [*segmentation fault* `(SIGSEV)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/SIG_types) raised due to stack overflow or similar things.

Comment: There is no consistent ABI for C++ exceptions.  Letting them propagate across module boundaries when you don't control the toolchains on both sides is asking for trouble.

Comment: `std::terminate_handler` looks like what I might be looking for. I'll take a look at that now, thanks.

Comment: Since I will be basically be the primary end user for my library (for the foreseeable future, and if that changes then my library will change), I will be using the same compiler for both the library and my projects.

Comment: After a good deal of testing, `std::terminate_handler` and `std::set_terminate` were **exactly** what I was looking for. I just register a global function with `set_terminate` that calls the proper functions with the Root singleton. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

> So I guess my TL;DR question is this: Is there a way, either through a
>   standard C++ function, or through some sort of manager class, to catch
>   when a library crashes and deal with it appropriately?

In the presence of things like structured exception handling and various segmentation faults and bus errors (the standard saying nothing about any of these things), the only way to prevent a crash in your library from taking down a user's application is to provide the library via a binary that the client program executes, and have the client be responsible for monitoring if the client process dies.

If you want the library to be linked directly into the user's application *there is nothing you can do* to absolutely be sure that a bug in your library won't crash the user's application. That's what unit, subsystem, and system test suites are for. Keep in mind that if your library crashes an application pretty much every OS I'm aware of will reclaim all the resources it allocated, so you don't need a global singleton to release heap memory: It will automatically be claimed by the OS at the point of the crash.

Finally note that if the library crashes the process is already in a bad state. There is no way that you can safely execute *any* code (for example what if the process heap is corrupt) at the point, including writing log messages or dumping a memory leak status.