# What catches stack overflow?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

If a stack keeps growing and growing, due to something like infinite recursion, what catches this and halts execution?  I would imagine the program would (erroneously) just start writing into the heap, as if it was stack memory, and keep on going until a potential crash due to heap corruption?

Comment: C++, but curiosity would remain for others as well.

Comment: Check if [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25146364/1413395) helps. for your particular problems.

Comment: You can't catch it in the same way as you do in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Most runtime systems leave a gap between the stack and the heap. Trying to access memory in this gap triggers an exception, which is translated into a Stack Overflow.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  The non-translated access will trigger it, I see.  Thank you, Barmar.

Comment: on linux you'll get a `signal` usually a segmentation fault. the difference is you can't catch a signal with a `try catch`

Answer (score 1):

This question is strongly related to virtual memory management of common operating Systems (e.g. x86). These operating systems use a a technique which is called 'paging'. It uses a table which maps physical memory (addresses of the RAM) to virtual addresses. Every task has its own table and therefore its own range of virtual addresses. If a task tries to access a memory block located at a virtual address which is not mapped to any physical address or tries to write at a virtual address which is mapped to a physical address with read-only flag set a page fault is triggered. This happens in case of a stack overflow. A page fault is an exception the operating system can catch. In most cases it will terminate the respective task (in modern operating systems there might of course be the possibility that the exception is propagated to the task itself). For more information see [osdev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging).